# What is the purpose of using define macro inside enum in C?

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor, glibc

I was looking at the value of `SOCK_DGRAM` which is defined in [`/bits/socket.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/source/bits/socket.h#L45) of `glibc`.

My question is that if I have a simple `enum` like:

```c
enum my_enum {
    SOME_VALUE = 1,
#define SOME_VALUE SOME_VALUE
    ANOTHER_VALUE = 2,
#define ANOTHER_VALUE ANOTHER_VALUE
}
```

What is the purpose of using `#define` macros in this case?